# How to save the user id against the record which is deleted by the specific user in laravel using soft deletes

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

Like in store method I can say that the record is created by this specific user. In this case the created by field is present in the database where the user id gets save.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
     $data = $request->all();
     $data['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
     Employee::create($data);
  }
```

This is just the simple shortcut code i have showed for store method it works fine, but how can i save user id against the deleted operation, like when a logged in user deletes the record which is soft deleted but i also want to store the current logged in user id in database. In destroy method we only pass the id to delete the specific record like:

```
  public function destroy($id)
  {
     $emp = Employee::findOrFail($id);
     $emp->delete();
  }
```

Here how can i pass the current logged in user id to database table like! i want to say the user id in deleted_by field in database table. This deletes the record but how to save user id against this delete operation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. Thanks

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
    $emp = Employee::findOrFail($id);
    $emp->deleted_by = Auth::user()->id;
    $emp->deleted_at = Carbon::now()->format("date format");
    $emp->update();
    }
```